# Convert KeyEvent.VK_SPACE to a String space

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

How can I convert `KeyEvent.VK_SPACE` (which is an integer) to an actual space?

```
String space = convertKeyEvent(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
System.out.println("Space=" + space + ".");
```

This should output

```
Space= .
```

And although this example uses Space, it should be a general converter for other characters as well, such as VK_0.

---

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Note that this DOES NOT work:

```
String space = KeyEvent.getKeyText(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
System.out.println("Space=" + space + ".");
```

In Eclipse, this outputs:

```
Space=?.
```

Comment: use KeyBinding instead, maybe if isn't there real reason, but not described in your question

Comment: Can you show how this would be done?

Comment: easy solution - cast to char - see below ;)

Comment: tags changed for better answer

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well - uh - did you once look at the actual value of `VK_SPACE`? It is 0x20 - that is the actual ASCII-value of space - that should give you some hint ;)

try:

```
char space = (char)VK_SPACE;
```

Comment: btw. VK_SPACE is not an exception - I suggest that you just look at the source code. It is included in the JDK1.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convert(int keyEvent){
    if(keyEvent == 32){
        return " ";
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String [] arg){
    System.out.println("Space=" + convert(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) + ".");
}
```

Comment: Okay...it should also be a general converter for things other than space.